# JSON data is not coming from local host

Tags: ios, json, localhost

I am trying to fetch json data from local host. I have done this so many times. But this time it is  not fetching data.

**Json data**

```
{ 
    "swimming_pool":"0", 
    "security":"0", 
    "lift":"0",
    "gym":"0",
    "reserved_parking":"0",
    "visitor_parking":"0",
    "power_backup":"0",
    "servant_room":"0",
    "tennis_court":"0",
    "rainwater_harvesting":"0",
    "waste_management":"0",
    "club_house":"0",
    "desc":"Dkkd",
    "city":"City",
    "pincode":"Pin Co",
    "locality":"locality",
    "no_of_beds":"1",
    "no_of_baths":"4"
}
```

**Client side code**

```
 {
        NSString *selectQuery=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost/FilterQuery.php?swimming_pool=%li&&security=%li&&lift=%li&&gym=%li&&visitor_parking=%li&&power_backup=%li&&servant_room=%li&&rainwater_harvesting=%li&&waste_management=%li&&clubhouse=%li&&Posdesc=%@&&no_of_baths=%li&&no_of_beds=%li&&pincode=%li&&locality=%@&&protypedesc=%@",(long)swimpoolb,(long)securityb,(long)liftb,(long)gymb,(long)visparkingb,(long)pbu,(long)servantroom,(long)rainwaterh,(long)wastemanagement,(long)clubHouse,possesion,(long)bathrooms,(long)bedrooms,(long)zipcode,locality,propertyType];

        NSString *newInsrStr = [selectQuery stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSData *dataaa=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:newInsrStr]];
        NSString *rr=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:dataaa encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"%@",rr);
        jsondataa=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataaa options:0 error:nil];
        //jsondataa is dictionary
        swimmingPool=@"";
        swimmingPool=[jsondataa objectForKey:@"swimming_pool"];
        security=@"";
        security=[jsondataa objectForKey:@"security"];
        lift=@"";
        lift=[jsondataa objectForKey:@"lift"];
        gym=@"";
        gym=[jsondataa objectForKey:@"gym"];
        reserved_parking=@"";
        reserved_parking=[jsondataa objectForKey:@"reserved_parking"];
        visitor_parking=@"";
        visitor_parking=[jsondataa objectForKey:@"visitor_parking"];
        power_backUp=@"";
        power_backUp=[jsondataa objectForKey:@"power_backup"];
        NSLog(@"%@,%@,%@,%@,%@,%@,%@",swimmingPool,security,lift,gym,reserved_parking,visitor_parking,power_backUp);
  }
```

**Output:**

> 2015-06-29 15:20:51.874 NexGV1[1684:60b] 
>  **Notice**: 
>   Undefined variable: tennis_court in
>   **/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/FilterQuery.php** on line
>   **21**
>   {"swimming_pool":"0","security":"0","lift":"0","gym":"0","reserved_parking":"0","visitor_parking":"0","power_backup":"0","servant_room":"0","tennis_court":"0","rainwater_harvesting":"0","waste_management":"0","club_house":"0","desc":"Dkkd","city":"City","pincode":"Pin
>   Co","locality":"locality","no_of_beds":"1","no_of_baths":"4"}
>   2015-06-29 15:20:51.875 NexGV1[1684:60b]
>   (null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null)

It is showing null value. Why?

Comment: You can use AFNetworking, you can easily fetch JSON data from this library https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

Comment: Yes it is running. Because it is giving the output of `NSLog(@"%@",rr);` But jsondataa is giving null values.@SukruK
 `

Comment: Use `+ (instancetype)dataWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDataReadingOptions)readOptionsMask error:(NSError **)errorPtr;` and pass an error object to the method so you can see if you're getting a response. Also check your local server is running.

Comment: @BhupeshKumar that doesn't mean it is running, if you go to `http://localhost/FilterQuery.php` you should be able to see if it is running.

Comment: I checked it and it is running.@sbarow

Comment: Check The jsondataa?
what's it's giving.

Comment: jsondataa is giving null value@DanialHussain

Comment: @BhupeshKumar remove 1 "&" everywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is suppose to be a comment but it's too long for a comment..**

So, your approach is json request via url, it is not the ideal for something like this it is confusing and hard to read..

I'm so lazy checking that very long url, so i'll just introduce you to this kind of approach..

```
NSString *selectQuery=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost/FilterQuery.php?swimming_pool=%li&&security=%li&&lift=%li&&gym=%li&&visitor_parking=%li&&power_backup=%li&&servant_room=%li&&rainwater_harvesting=%li&&waste_management=%li&&clubhouse=%li&&Posdesc=%@&&no_of_baths=%li&&no_of_beds=%li&&pincode=%li&&locality=%@&&protypedesc=%@",(long)swimpoolb,(long)securityb,(long)liftb,(long)gymb,(long)visparkingb,(long)pbu,(long)servantroom,(long)rainwaterh,(long)wastemanagement,(long)clubHouse,possesion,(long)bathrooms,(long)bedrooms,(long)zipcode,locality,propertyType];

NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:selectQuery]];
```

You can convert that url to request then use the `NSURLConnection` below..

---

```
__block NSMutableData *fragmentData = [NSMutableData data];

__block id serializedResponse;

[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] cancelAllOperations];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
 {
     [fragmentData appendData:data];

     if ([data length] == 0 && error == nil)
     {
         NSLog(@"No response from server");
     }
     else if (error != nil && error.code == NSURLErrorTimedOut)
     {
         NSLog(@"Request time out");
     }
     else if (error != nil)
     {
         NSLog(@"Unexpected error occur: %@", error.localizedDescription);
     }
     else if ([data length] > 0 && error == nil)
     {
         if ([fragmentData length] == [response expectedContentLength])
         {
             NSLog(@"Received %f of data from server.", (CGFloat)[response expectedContentLength]);

             serializedResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                  options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments
                                                                    error:&error];
             NSLog(@"%@", serializedResponse);
             // or
             NSLog(@"%@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:fragmentData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
         }
     }
 }];
```

And also if you like the easy way to make a request using the `NSURLConnection` above.

```
- (NSURLRequest *)convertToRequest:(NSString *)stringURL withDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary
{

    NSError *error = nil;

    NSData *JSONData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionary options:0 error:&error];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody: JSONData];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Encoding"];

    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[JSONData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];


    return request;
}
```

and using it like:

```
NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = @{
                                  @"swimming_pool": [NSNumber numberWithLong:(long)swimpoolb],
                                  @"security" : [NSNumber numberWithLong:(long)securityb],
                                  .. and so on
                                }; 
NSURLRequest *request = [ImplementationClass convertToRequest:YourServerURL withDictionary: jsonDictionary];
```

and in the server it should be:

```
$handle = fopen('php://input','r');
$jsonInput = fgets($handle);
$json_decoded = json_decode($jsonInput,true);

$json_decoded['swimming_pool']; 
$json_decoded['security'];
```

Hope this is informative and helpful...